# Easiest way to get to CDG from Paris with big luggage

Tags: luggage, airport-transfer, paris, cdg

My partner and I are coming from Château d'Eau Metro station and need to get to Charles de Gaulle Airport airport T1. We each are carrying a 30kg suitcase with wheels and a 10kg handcarry. What is the easiest way to get to the train with minimal walking?

We are thinking of taking a cab to Gare du Nord but which entrance should we use to get to the RER B to airport without having to navigate flights of stairs?

Comment: You might even be faster walking from Chateau d'Eau to Gare du Nord than loading and unloading your suitcases into a taxi. It is 1km. Metro in no case. How about a bus (line 30)?

Comment: Ask he cab driver to drop you at CDG. He will be happy to do this.

Answer (score 6):

### To Peak or Not to Peak?

Having done it a bunch of times, I would never advise taking the RER B from the city centre with that much luggage. Especially if you are leaving during peak hours, times at which the RER becomes as packed as the Japanese metro. There's usually no space for people, let alone heavy luggage that's hard to move around. I would therefore advise you consider the following solutions, ordered by cost (all prices are for one person, single journey, quoted as of August 2015):

1. [EasyBus](http://www.easybus.com/en/paris-cdg-airport/paris-price-comparison) - (starting from) 2`EUR`<sup>1</sup> - 60 minutes*
2. [Roissy Bus](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61872/roissybus/) - 11`EUR` - 75 minutes*
3. [Cars Air France Ligne 2](http://en.lescarsairfrance.com/lignes-horaires/ligne-cdg-aeroport-paris-etoile-champs-elysees.html) - 17`EUR` - 75 minutes*
4. [Cars Air France Ligne 3](http://en.lescarsairfrance.com/lignes-horaires/ligne-cdg-aeroport-paris-gare-montparnasse.html) - 17.5`EUR` - 75 minutes*
5. [Taxi](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/taxi/paris-cdg-taxi) - 50-70`EUR` - 60 minutes*

*Journey times are indicated in an ideal situation in which you hit no traffic.
<sup>1</sup>Minimum fare available if booked enough time in advance

The reasoning being that by taking any of these solutions you'll be moving your luggage around only twice: getting in and out of the vehicle. Moreover you mentioned that a taxi would take you to Gare du Nord, therefore you can use the same system to get to the departure points for any of the buses I linked.

On the other hand, if you are leaving outside of peak hour, and are lucky to jump on the express train, you could consider the RER B. Gare du Nord has both elevators and escalators which should be helpful to move around that much luggage. [Here is a page regarding elevator availability in the station.](http://www.infomobi.com/en/disabled-travellers/accessible-public-transport/accessible-stations-and-stops/availability-of-the-stations-elevators/?cHash=d2d408909ab1287ea3c2edb9abed1c02&tx_stifinfomobi_pi3[externalcode]=8727100&tx_stifinfomobi_pi3[lineexternalcode]=800%3AH)

For more comprehensive information here is [the CDG page on airport access](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle) and on public transport.

Comment: @pnuts Strange. [The linked easybus page says that prices start at 2€ one way.](http://www.easybus.com/en/paris-cdg-airport/paris-price-comparison) You are of course right in that by adding 2€ one can book a return journey.

Comment: you may know the specific answer to this .. http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/71461/19233  cheers

Comment: This answer probably needs a bit of an update, 4 years later... No more EasyBus, the Cars Air France are now called Le Bus Direct, and taxis now have a fixed fee from Paris to CDG.

Comment: @jcaron Go ahead and edit away. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already in a cab when getting to Gare du Nord, the easiest way would be to have the cab drop you at the airport.

The only exception to this would be if the train drops you in a favorable location within the airport so that you don't have to travel much with your luggage.

Comment: @pnuts ah...good point.